# Java 8 pass a clickListener as parameter using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, vaadin

i want to create a method, which create a button in vaadin with parameter.

```
private void addButton(Button button, String toolTip, FontAwesome fontAwesome, ... clickEvent){
        button = new Button(fontAwesome);
        button.setDescription(toolTip);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.addClickListener(event -> clickEvent);
    }
```

by call:

```
addButton(newButton, "My test Button", FontAwesome.PLUS_SQUARE, someObject.do())
```

how can i set the clickListener as parameter with lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void addButton(Button button, String toolTip, FontAwesome fontAwesome, Button.ClickListener clickEvent){
    button = new Button(fontAwesome);
    button.setDescription(toolTip);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.addClickListener(clickEvent);
}
```

You'll then call your method like this `addButton(newButton, "Test", o, evt -> someMethod());`

**[EDIT]** : while I think it answers your question please note that the `new Button` won't be accessible from the method caller which is likely a bug in your code, you should consider returning the button instead